# UK Standard Visitor visa application to sit for PLAB 1 without savings or job

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am a medical doctor in Pakistan. I have been on a career break to allow myself to study full time for the IELTS exam (from which I recently got the required band score) and PLAB 1. I have now registered and paid for the PLAB 1 exam in UK for June 2016, as the next sitting in Pakistan is in November 2016 and I feel like I am ready to do the exam sooner.

Due to having no current employment, my savings are limited (around 25,000 Pakistani Rupees) but I live with my parents and do not have any financial commitments at home.  My savings have depleted in the past ten months whilst I have taken a career break and the money has been used for my own personal expenses. My trip to the UK is being funded by my grandfather who is a British citizen. He is a retired doctor with a good NHS pension. He has provided me with:

- 6 months bank statements which clearly show his pension deposits
- Letter from NHS Pensions stating his pension
- Sponsorship letter stating that he will pay for my PLAB exam fee, travel, accommodation and subsistinence costs whilst in the UK
- Copy of British passport
- Document confirming that he owns the house he lives in mortgage-free
- Confirmation email from GMC stating he has paid the PLAB exam fee.

Without large personal savings and no current job (but I have job offers now) would my application be rejected or is the strong sponsorship going to be good enough?

Are there any other documents I should consider submitting that may help me get a visa?

Comment: Be sure to read http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=plab  and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: The part that says "...they do not relieve the applicant of demonstrating ties..."

Comment: You said your grandfather is a British citizen, settled in the UK. Is it possible that one of your parents is a British citizen? If this is true, then it might be that you are already a British citizen (by descent or otherwise). You may wish to investigate this possibility.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, nice call.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Do you think I should submit my
Fathers rental agreement for the property we live at including payment receipts/bank statements to show he is paying rent in property I live at with my family?

Comment: @Mangal If your grandfather was born in the UK, you are probably eligible for an [ancestry visa](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa).

Comment: He is my mother's uncle. Not my direct grandfather (my grandfathers brother )

Comment: Ah OK. Bad luck...

Comment: @gayotfow do you think I should submit my father's rental agreement along with proof that he pays the rent (in form of bank slips confirming amount being paid every month). This will then prove that I am not paying rent. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/eligibility), you need to show the following for a Standard Visitor Visa:

1. you’ll leave the UK at the end of your visit
2. you’re able to support yourself and any dependents for the duration
   of your trip
3. you’re able to pay for your return or onward journey and any other
   costs relating to your visit
4. you have proof of any business or other activities you want to do in
   the UK, as allowed by the Visitor Rules

For 1, I would suggest documents detailing job offers (if outside the UK) and a letter from your parents saying you have been living there and will return (if this is the case). The letter from your Grandfather along with his bank statements should tick 2 and 3 (read [this document](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) Section 4 about sending too many documents). For 4, you are required ([here](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf)) to have a letter (I would definitely recommend hard-copy) from the GMC that you are entered for the exam.
As regards whether you will be approved, as a well-qualified doctor with family in the UK I see no reason why not. But the only way to find out is to apply.

Comment: He is my mother's uncle. So not my direct grandfather.