# Travel to the UK without a job

Tags: proof-of-employment, standard-visitor-visas

I'm a doctor doing my internship now and it will finish by the end of February. I will be jobless till applying for residency in May and I'm planning to sit for PLAB 2 examination and travel to the UK in April.

Can I apply for visa (Standard Visitor) during my internship in February, or will my application have a high probability of being refused, as I won't be employed by the time I will be in the UK?

What documents can support me?

Comment: Have you read answers to the [related questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=PLAB+is%3Aq)? For example, is your question already answered by the existing answers to [UK Standard Visitor visa application to sit for PLAB 1 without savings or job](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67462/uk-standard-visitor-visa-application-to-sit-for-plab-1-without-savings-or-job)

Comment: Hi and welcome! I'm minded to mark this as a duplicate to one of the numerous PLAB questions in the archives linked by @RedGrittyBrick (to whom thanks).  We don't take bets on probability questions and we're not a forum. Please examine the archives and then edit your question so that it has 'laser-like' focus on a single issue, thanks.